# jQuery Autocomplete images with options

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am a newbie to jQuery.But really fascinated on it.Hats off to jQuery Team

I have an aspx page where i want to implement an auto complete feature  for a text box where user will type to search products.If they type,I wanto to show products with name a and their images to in the option.I have a DB table with 3 columns ProductId,ProductName and Image Name.

I tried the jQuery autocomplete plug gin.But could not find a solution for my requirement.Can any one guide me how to go ahead.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to provide the product name and image url back to the autocomplete plugin from your server-side code.  You can then override `formatItem` in the plugin [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) to modify the markup.  Essentially, you'll need to create the html that shows the name and picture.  See the image search demo at http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/.  Here's the code from that demo:

```
$("#imageSearch").autocomplete("images.php", {
    width: 320,
    max: 4,
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
        return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
    },
    formatResult: function(data, value) {
        return value.split(".")[0];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson. I tried the same example.But How do i return those,?  As a list item ?(in <li> tag ?) or an HTML table rows ? .Where can i specify the product id,When  a user select a product from the drop down , i want to take the product id also

Comment: I usually send the data back as JSON and include a parse method to extract the data and "objectify" it.  By default I think it expects text with newline separators between "rows".  You could have the fields separated by commas and parse each row if the image url itself doesn't contain the information you need as in the example.